# How can I control mosquitto_loop() for subcribing a message?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I want to have a sample about mosquittopp `loop()`.

My code is:

```
 MqttWrapper *mqttHdl = new MqttWrapper("sanggil", "***.**.**.***", 1883);
    int rc;
    while(1){
        rc = mqttHdl->loop();
        printf( "while  %d\n", rc);
        if(rc){
            mqttHdl->reconnect();
        }

}
```

I used a sample code in mosquitto c++ lib with my project.
Because it has `while()` function in main function, other codes in my project cannot work normally. 
`while()` function is called about once per second.

I just want that `subcribe()` function is called when some message is only arriveded from broker without `loop()`.

Do I have to use `while()` function to listen a message from broker?

If I use `while()` function, it uses most of the resources resource in the program.

Answer (score 0):

Start a separate thread to run the moquitto_loop function